# Compare XML file (attributes, nodes and text)

Tags: c#, xml

I know that there are already several questions about this topic, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I already tried everything with Diff in the name, XMLUnit, FatAntelope, xdocument and several more.
My main problem with These approaches was, that I either don't get the output I want or no output at all. The best approach was XmlDiffLib with the following code:

```
var exampleA = File.ReadAllText(@"Error0.xml");
var exampleB = File.ReadAllText(@"Error1.xml");

var diff = new XmlDiff(exampleA, exampleB);

diff.CompareDocuments(new XmlDiffOptions());

Console.WriteLine(diff.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

but it only shows me changed text (f.e. `<error>TextThatCanBeDetected</error>`). I want additional to check for changed attributes (`<error same="IWantToCheckThisToo"/>`)

***Inline Edit***
diff has other flaws too, for example if in the new XML is an extra tag it won't be recognized as one
***End inline edit***

I would be very happy to help me with this problem, below is an example of the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
<header>
</header>
<body>
    <error name="MyName"> MyInnerXML </error>
</body>
</message>
```

(Note that the original file is around 100 lines long)

***EDIT***

So one answer was to change the CompareDocuments method to

```
diff.CompareDocuments(new XmlDiffOptions { IgnoreAttributes=false });
```

but the output was [image: this]

(I used wudri and hudri for the name tag, it tells me that wudri is not found but nothing about hudri)

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify to not ignore attributes in your XmlDiffOptions:

```
diff.CompareDocuments(new XmlDiffOptions { IgnoreAttributes = false });
```

Moreover you need to specify to compare both directions to identify both values for the differing node:

```
diff.CompareDocuments(new XmlDiffOptions { IgnoreAttributes = false, TwoWayMatch = true });
```

Comment: Well, that didn't do antything

Comment: I tested with your sample Xml and it clearly identified the difference between `name="MyName1"`and `name="MyName2"`.

Comment: Adding the `TwoWayMatch = true`option should give you the desired result, identifying both values for the differing node.

Comment: Well _basically_ it works. The output is quite hard to read but the desired output is there. Problem: it doesn't work with my 100+ lines like mentioned in my question. Even the developer of XmlDiffLib states this as a problem with his code on [github](https://github.com/BrutalSimplicity/XmlDiffLib/issues/2)